# Woocommerce fields required not showing as required

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

So I've recently used some hooks and filters to add and remove some fields on my checkout page.

For some reason, my billing address is not required by default. Is there a setting or configuration for that? I've then tried to set the fields as required which presents and error and does not let the customer continue without filling the field, but it does not highlight the box with a red border or show the "*" highlighting the fact it is a required field.

Here is what I've added.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'checkout_required_fields', 9999 );

function checkout_required_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_state']['required'] = true; 
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['required'] = true;

    return $fields;
}
```

**My 2 questions are:**

1. Shouldn't the billing address be required by default?
2. With trying to override and then set it as required, why is not showing this to the user?

Comment: **Yes they are required by default**, so the explanation could be that your theme is overriding this… As there is different hooks to make this happen, it's not easy to find out which one is the right one.